# Circular Dependency in Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Someone suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852261/c-tuple-vs-struct) using tuples instead of all public structures. And I found it useful. But my problem is now with the following section:

```
using Edge = std::tuple<Node_wp,//From Node
                        Node_wp>;//To Node
using Edge_wp = std::weak_ptr<Edge>;

using Node = std::tuple<std::vector<Edge_wp>,//Incoming Edges
                        std::vector<Edge_wp>>;//Outgoing Edges
using Node_wp = std::weak_ptr<Node>;
```

How can I overcome this circular dependency in template parameters. Forward declaration (with the knowledge in my possession) won't work since type Edge is can not be formed without knowing type Node and visa versa.

Obviously I can make one of them `struct` and be done with it. But it will be ugly to break symmetry in access.

Comment: didnt read the linked answer, but I disagree with the premise, just prefer structs over tuples. If your edge connects `Node_wp`s then why not declare it as such? Also `from_node` and `to_node` would be much better names than `first` and `second`

Comment: @tobi303 They suggest using 'enum's for readability. But real catch here is not implementing member functions (sorting, equality, serialization etc.) which are already part of 'tuple' (or libraries supporting tuple).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `struct` and public inheritance to fix your circular dependency issue. `Node` will become a `struct` wrapper around an `std::tuple`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

struct Node;
using Node_wp = std::weak_ptr<Node>;

using Edge = std::tuple<Node_wp,  // From Node
                        Node_wp>; // To Node
using Edge_wp = std::weak_ptr<Edge>;

struct Node : std::tuple<std::vector<Edge_wp>, // Incoming Edges
                         std::vector<Edge_wp>> // Outgoing Edges
{
    using std::tuple<std::vector<Edge_wp>, std::vector<Edge_wp>>::tuple;
};
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @ifyalciner Why did this answer get accepted? This is actually the same as initially proposed solution: "Obviously I can make one of them struct".

Comment: @VTT what I meant was using struct as itself (I couldn't think of using inheritance to break circle). Now struct wrapper is just a shallow cover over tuple. And I can use it as tuple. But if you have other suggestions instead of inheritance I would like to hear as well.

Comment: @VTT: this technique still exposes `std::tuple`'s interface. The OP mentioned `struct`, but not inheritance: therefore I (rightly) assumed that he/she didn't consider public inheritance and was just referring to a "traditional" `struct`.