# Python object encapsulation security

Tags: python, security, encapsulation

I have a question, and my decision in choosing Python as a possible language for a bigger project depends on the answer - which I cannot come up with myself:

We all know that Python has no *real* object encapsulation, so there is nothing like "private" properties of an object. Regarding this issue, Guido van Rossum says that one can access hidden parts of a foreign object without being "allowed" to, with "we are all adults", "just don't do it".
I can live perfectly well with that, as long as the software I write is in my own hand, so I am responsible for my own errors and just can try to avoid such things.

BUT - and here comes my question:
What if I provide a plugin framework with some plugins that have some extension points, and many of the plugins are by OTHER people, maybe ones that I cannot trust completely.

How do I prevent exposing internals of my framework from being accessed by a plugin?

Is there a way to achieve this, or is the only way to use Python having confidence that no one will abuse my API?

Comment: Some google search terms to help you out: [Sandbox python](http://www.google.com/search?q=sandboxed+python).

Comment: I don't really see how this is a security issue. Who is being guarded from what?

Comment: I really have to admit that I slightly dislike the tone of *"We all know that Python has no real object encapsulation"* :)

Comment: @ErikAllik: at least we all know. C++ and Java programmers are still fooling themselves.

Comment: What would be an example of "Abusing your API"?

Comment: how about `api._permissions['erik'].add('delete', '*')`?

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr: exactly what I meant, yes. Changing "internal" members of an object that are meant to be "private" in security terms, like _ or __ fields.

Comment: @ErikAllik: Python HAS no object encapsulation in the sense of keeping private members really private... I love Python (as far as I know it by now) - I must admit that I am no proffessional programmer (else I wouldn't have to ask questions like this one ;-) )

Comment: @DrOetker: so do C++, Java and C# keep private members "really private"? because I've demonstrated that they dont; so what is your definition or "really private"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should never really rely on `private`, `public` etc for security (as in "protection against malicious code and external threats"). They are meant as something to keep the programmer from shooting himself in the foot, not as a (computer) security measure. You can also easily access private member fields of C++ objects, as long as you bypass static compiler checks and go straight to the memory, but would you say that C++ lacks true encapsulation?

- For **C++**, see http://phoxis.org/2012/01/25/accessing-private-data-members-directly-outside-from-its-class-in-c/
- Same about the **JVM** (and thus **Java**): [How do I read a private field in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java)
- And (more or less) the same about **CLR** (i.e. **.NET**): [Does reflection breaks the idea of private methods, because private methods can be access outside of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300680/does-reflection-breaks-the-idea-of-private-methods-because-private-methods-can)

So you would never really use `private` or `protected` as a security measure against malicious plugins in C++ nor Java, and I assume C# as well.

Your best bet is to run your plugins in a separate process and expose the core API over IPC/RPC or even web service, or run them in a [sandbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=sandboxed+python) (as per what @MarkHildreth pointed out). Alternatively, you can set up a certification and signing process for your plugins so that you can review and filter out potentially malicious plugins before they even get distributed.

**NOTE:**

You can actually achieve true encapsulation using lexical closures:

```
def Foo(param):
    param = [param]  # because `nonlocal` was introduced only in 3.x
    class _Foo(object):
        @property
        def param(self):
            return param[0]
        @param.setter
        def param(self, val):
            param[0] = val
    return _Foo()

foo = Foo('bar')
print foo.param  # bar
foo.param = 'baz'
print foo.param  # baz
# no way to access `foo._param` or anything
```

...but even then, the value is actually still relatively easily accessible via reflection:

```
>>> foo.__class__.param.fget.__closure__[0].cell_contents[0] = 'hey'
>>> foo.param
'hey'
```

...and even if this weren't possible, we'd still be left with [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) which allows direct memory access, bypassing any remaining cosmetic "restrictions":

```
import ctypes
arr = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 64).from_address(id(foo))
```

and now you can just assign to `arr` or read from it; although you'd have to work hard to traverse pointers from there down to the actual memory location where `.param` is stored, but it proves the point.

Comment: Well put. Not only is this answer itself very helpful, but those links are very interesting and useful as well. You made a very good distinction with encapsulation being more of a programming tool rather than a security measure.

Comment: +1. I too tend to lament Python's lack of real access control, but only because it makes it too easy for me to write crappy OOP in my own classes. Even with third party classes, learning the public API is as much effort as I feel usually inclined to put in, I can't say I've ever felt sufficiently motivated to poke into the internals to the extent where having access control over someone else's classes would have made any appreciable difference.

Comment: @ErikAllik Thank you very much - this was the answer I was searching for. Didn't know that it's possible in Java to access private members. In C++ I thought so, but I still put it into the Voodoo drawer...

Comment: Hm. I think this is, despite being a good approach in a security manner, not viable for programming a snappy application - a framework which heavily depends on calling the APIs functions does slow down and does not scale very well when having all API calls via RPC, am I right? I mean e.g. exposing functions for displaying dozens/hundreds of GUI elements on the screen via RPC calls...

Comment: @DrOetker: the sandbox approach is not very good then either, I guess; so your best option is probably to just trust the code you've verified and certified/approved to be safe and not introduce any overhead in the form of a security layer.

Comment: @ErikAllik Even if this was 2 years ago, I wanted to say thanks. Certification is the way to go here then.

Comment: @NerDoc: I appreciate you coming back here with this and sharing with us! Is there a more elaborate story behind this?

Comment: Not yet. But to come. What I'm planning is a Open Source Electronic Medical Record for (firstly) small practicians. And I'll do this in Python - and it should have a plugin API to be extended by other companies e.g. ECG devices etc. Currently I am in the state of planning (and during to the lack of time (I'm a doc myself) this is ongoing a little delayed. ;-)