# Convert C++ class with 150+ variables to Json object

Tags: c++, json, class

I am codding in C++ and using JsonCPP. I have a class with 150+ variables and I would like to know if it is possible to convert all the variables to Json at once. I would like not to do this :

myClass.h

```
class myClass
{
   std::string var0;
   std::string var1;
   //...
   std::string var150;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() 
{
   Json::Value param;

   param["var0"] = var0;
   param["var1"] = var1;
   //...
   param["var150"] = var150;
}
```

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: Are you sure there's no way to refactor it? Maybe, you could benefit from inheritance, for instance? What kind of class is it, if you don't mind me asking? Just curious. I've never seen a class with so many variables.

Comment: I am working with a vulnerability scanner API, Nessus. I need to create and configure a scan policy and there is a lot of variables in it.

Comment: Are all the member variable the same type ? If yes, can't you use a ``std::map`` where the key would be the variable name ? You could then iterate over the map to serialise into JSON.

Comment: Why doesn't it have some sort of container, like a vector or a map, to store those variables?

Comment: Unfortunately the member variable arn't the same type.

Comment: maybe a container and a variant (boost or std) would work ?

Comment: You [can't do that in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143120/convert-string-to-variable-name-or-variable-type) and with a good reason. Use the container such as [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead.

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflexivity, you have to use a library which simulates that as [boost hana](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/#tutorial-introspection-json)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create the structure in [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). You'll still need to list all the members once (in a .proto file instead of a .cpp file) but then you can use the protobuf library [to convert to or from JSON](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.json_util), and it has other handy abilities too (e.g. iterate over the members, convert to a binary format, use with [gRPC](https://grpc.io/)).