# How to get declared variables with specific number at the ends c++

Tags: c++

I have void function:

```
void setPreyFreeReroll(uint8_t column, uint32_t value) {
    rerollTime << column = value;
}
```

rerollTime variable is defined as rerollTime0, rerollTime1, rerollTime2.
"column" is number 0,1,2 how do I get variable with this number?
Using it like I try is getting me error undefinied variable.

reroll variables:

```
uint32_t rerollTime0 = 0;
uint32_t rerollTime1 = 0;
uint32_t rerollTime2 = 0;
```

Comment: Show the declaration of `rerollTime`, your description doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to use an array?

Comment: If I understood, you want to create a variable from a string by concatenation of `rerollTime` and an integer. This is [not possible in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143120/convert-string-to-variable-name-or-variable-type).

Comment: So I will have to create separate function to get every single variable?

Comment: No, you can use an `std::map<string, uint32_t>` ; because the key is a `string` you should obtain the behaviour you want.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot just use an array? `reRollTime[3]` would give you the same effect you have now (except it would actually work). You just access the variables using array indexing: `reRollTime[0]`, `reRollTime[1]`, `reRollTime[2]`.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray. I'm newbie so that's why I didnt use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in all honesty your code is so far from being c++ it is hard to tell exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

```
uint32_t rerollTime[3];

void setPreyFreeReroll(uint8_t column, uint32_t value) {
    rerollTime[column] = value;
}
```

Comment: It isn't *that* hard to understand. He's trying to concatenate `rerollTime` and `column`, and he's using the stream insertion operator to do it. Now, obviously that's wrong, because variable names are not strings, but the question is not as unclear as you make it out to be.

Comment: @CodyGray when i first read his post (before it was edited) i thought he might be trying to bit shift and store the three values in a single variable.  so not as obvious as you make it out