# How can get the size of the data type which is inside the string?

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, visual-c++

how I can get the datatype size that is inside the string

string a = "int"

string b = "float"

I want to get the int and float datatype size...

Comment: Why have you tagged multiple languages?

Comment: Wow, not possible i think, at least not without a lot of work. But the question must be asked, why to you think you need to do this? Whatever bigger problem you are trying to solve, there is a better way.

Comment: C# and C++ are two very distinct languages and the answer (if any) will be different for both.

Comment: Unless you are planning to use a lot of types, I would go for a simple switch or a series of if statements for simplicity.

Comment: For C++, you might consider using a std::map.  Use the string as the index, and the value of size_t. i.e.  myMap.insert (std::make_pair("float", sizeof(float)));  myMap.insert(std::make_pair("int", size(int))); etc.  Look up is similarly easy.

Answer (score 2):

In c++ when you only use primitve types you can do it with if and else:

```
std::size_t getSizeOfType(std::string& str) {
    if (str == "int") {
        return sizeof(int);
    }
    else if (str == "float") {
        return sizeof(float);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can do that for every primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a string to a variable data type and, then, get its size.

It's impossible to do that in C++, since there's no language support for such conversion (see [Convert string to variable name or variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143120/convert-string-to-variable-name-or-variable-type)).

However, you can do the *if-else* structure as proposed by TmCrafz in a previous answer.

Answer (score -1):

When you use string you can access the size using,

```
string a = "int";
System.out.println("length: " + a.length);
```

If not what you need I did not understand your question correctly.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to get the size of the actual type indicated in the string, not the length of the string itself.