# How i can get variable name in c++ without define

Tags: c++, variables

I'm looking for a function that returns a variable name

Theoretical example

```
template <typename Type>
std::string GetVarName(Type Var)
{
    //Get Name 
    return Variable_name;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting a variable name to a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386861/converting-a-variable-name-to-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Please give an example of how you want to use this code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Perhaps use a data structure instead? Like a `std::vector<T>` or `std::map<key, value>`.

Comment: What's the purpose? it looks like a XY problem

Comment: C++ is compiled. The compiler removes variable names.

Comment: stringify with pre-processor is the way to go actually.

Comment: `int i = 3; char const* GetVarName(int& x) { if (&x == &i) return "i"; return "unknown;" }` Add all the variables you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to stringify the variable using the preprocessor. In the posted link by Schultke there are some examples using macro in order to achieve that.

Comment: I believe "without define" means without the preprocessor