# Using a user variable to access a member of struct? C++

Tags: c++, variables, struct

Say I have the following struct:

```
struct movie {
    char movie_name[32];
    int rating;
    int release_year;
    char location;
}
```

Normally, I would access the rating by saying "movie.rating".

For this project, I have to take input from a text file. I will read a variable such as "movie_name" or "rating" or "release_year" from the file, and given that variable, I have to access the corresponding element of the struct.

Ex: if the input file reads "movie_name", then I want to access movie.movie_name. How do I do this **without** making 4 if statements? Is there another way?

```
if(input == "movie_name")
   movie.movie_name = ... 
else if(input == "rating")
   movie.rating = ...
```

The real struct I'm working with has 20+ members, so I am trying to find a more efficient way to write this code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add member functions. Than you can put pointers to those in a map. This is `C` code masquerading as C++. And if not than all of your comparisons are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ it is not possible to access variable using a string; so there is no way to do this using the struct you provide. A map might be an alternative:

```
map<string, int>
```

but then each variable will map on the same type of variable (int in this case)... You should look to the related questions: [How to use a string as a variable name in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641751/how-to-use-a-string-as-a-variable-name-in-c) and [Convert string to variable name or variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143120/convert-string-to-variable-name-or-variable-type)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called reflection. unfortunately, it is not supported in C++. One solution to your problem which is not an optimal one of course is to implement your struct as `map` of `pair<key,value>` as follow:

```
struct movie {
   std::map<string,ValueType> foo;
}
```

However, the problem is the ValueType. If boost is available, Then this could be a better solution:

```
struct movie {
   std::map<string,boost::variant<typeX, typeY>> foo;
}
```