# C++ : value from variable as variable

Tags: c++

how to print variable from value of other variable in c++
i'm just new in c++.

in php we can make/print a variable by the value of other variable.
like this.

```
$example = 'foo';
$foo = 'abc';
echo ${$example}; // the output will 'abc'
```

how can i solve this in c++?

Comment: C++ doesn't have this feature (which is reflection): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911442/access-variable-value-using-string-representing-variables-name-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at it another way, it's just indirection, which C++ uses extensively.  An analogous example in C++ might be...

```
using namespace std;
string foo = "abc";
string* example = &foo;
cout << *example << endl;  // The output will 'abc'
```

...or using a reference instead of a pointer...

```
using namespace std;
string foo = "abc";
string& example = foo;
cout << example << endl;  // The output will 'abc'
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.

The only way to emulate this (well sort of) is to use a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)

Answer (score 1):

Getting a variable/member by its name is called reflection/introspection.

There is no reflection mechanism in C++, and basically you can't do that.