# learning c++, outputting variable in structure

Tags: c++

Say I have a structure as follows

```
struct stock{
    string ticker;
    double price;
    double volume;
    double eps;
};
```

If I want to output one of the variables such as price when asked for it would I have to do a large if/else or switch statement to match up the user input with the member or is there a more elegant way to do it because I know `stock.userInput` does not work.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911442/access-variable-value-using-string-representing-variables-name-in-c

Comment: Better understanding the question, try a `std::map`. Since the second can be a number of types, perhaps something like Boost's Any for the second type would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no special keyword to find your variable(sorry to burst your bubble), You would have to use a logical statement. It would go along:

```
cout << "What would you like to see? (1)Price (2)etc...etc...";
cin >> input;
switch(input)
{
    case 1:
        cout << Obj.Price;
    break;
    case 2:
        cout << //....
    break;
}
```

I personally like using keys and a switch statement, it tends to be a lot cleaner and easier to go back and modify later in the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct stock s1;
cout<<" price is:"<< s1.price;
```

Comment: The `struct` part is useless in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the large `switch`/`if` statement, you can use `map` with `string` and a pointer-to-member. Assuming your `stock` struct, you can use:

Define the map (for doubles here) and initialize it:

```
std::map<std::string,double stock::*> double_members;
double_members["price"]=&stock::price;
double_members["volume"]=&stock::volume;
double_members["eps"]=&stock::eps;
```

And use it to look up  some values:

```
stock stock1;
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
if (double_members.find(input)!=double_members.end()) 
    std::cerr << "Value for " << input << " is: " << stock1.*double_members[input] << std::endl;
else
    std::cerr << "There's no field called " << input << std::endl;
```

It's limited to a single type, but you can't have a statement like `std::cerr << A;` and have `A`'s type resolved during runtime. If you care only about `string` (or any other, but always the same) representation of the values, then you can wrap `map`s for different types in a class that searches all of them and outputs the value converted to a `string` (or something).

But it's probably easier to have the `if` statement, unless the `struct` is really big.

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay with you that it doesn't work with g++ 4.7.1 and earlier (but does work with Visual C++ 11.0 and later), then like …

```
#include <sstream>      // std::ostringstream
#include <string>       // std::string
using namespace std;

struct Stock
{
    string ticker;
    double price;
    double volume;
    double eps;

    string toString() const
    {
        ostringstream stream;
        stream
            << "Stock("
            << "ticker='" << ticker << "', "
            << "price=" << price << ", "
            << "volume=" << volume << ", "
            << "eps=" << eps
            << ")";
        return stream.str();
    }

    Stock(): ticker(), price(), volume(), eps() {}
};

#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool err( string const& s )
{
    cerr << "!" << s << endl;
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

string lineFromUser( string const& prompt )
{
    string line;
    cout << prompt;
    getline( cin, line )
        || err( "oh my, failed to read line of input" );
    return line;
}

void cppMain()
{
    Stock stock;
    stock.price = 1.23;

    string const s = stock.toString();
    cout << s << endl;
    string const fieldname = lineFromUser( "Which field u want? " );
    regex const valuespec( fieldname + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^,\\)]*)" );  // 
    smatch what;
    if( regex_search( s, what, valuespec ) )
    {
        cout << "As we all know already, " << what.str() << "." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout
            << "!Sorry, there's no field named '"
            << fieldname << "'"
            << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cppMain();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Example usage:

```
[d:\dev\test]
> foo
Stock(ticker='', price=1.23, volume=0, eps=0)
Which field u want? eps
As we all know already, eps=0.

[d:\dev\test]
> _
```