# How do you use a string or char to identify a variable by name in C++?

Tags: c++

What I mean is, how do I use a char, which I can iterate, to identify a variable?
So if:

```
int cheese = 1337;
string identifier = "cheese";
```

How do I use this string "identifier" to identify the variable cheese and return its value?

Comment: it's not possible in c++

Comment: C++ ulike Java does not have reflection so a program once is fully compiled, linked and loaded, it loses all reference to symbol names. The only thing is had is addresses.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911442/access-variable-value-using-string-representing-variables-name-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You don't.**

Instead, you lay out your data differently, perhaps using a key-value store?

```
std::map<std::string, int> myData;
myData["cheese"] = 1337;

// ...

const std::string identifier = "cheese";
std::cout << myData[identifier] << '\n';   // 1337
```

Comment: I see. Hmm. I there any way to do it in Java? Apart from using the hashmaps, or other dictionary storage?

Comment: @JackRaiden: in... Java???

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, int> vars;
    vars.insert(make_pair("cheese", 1337));
    vars.insert(make_pair("geese", 1338));
    if (vars.find("cheese") != vars.end())
        cout << vars.at("cheese");
    return 0;
}
```