# C/C++ Possible to get a "list" of instance members by querying a class?

Tags: c++, c, instance-variables

Suppose we have a struct in C++:

```
struct foobar
{
      int age; 
      bool hot;
      String name
};
```

Is there a way, programatically, to query the above struct to extract its instance members? For example:

```
String[] members = magicClass.getInstanceMembers(foobar);
```

Members would have `["age", "hot", "name"]` as it's values.

Possible? The reason why I ask is because I have structs that change over time (variables added/removed).  I want to be able to create auto-generating Lua files with this saved data.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry about the pedantry but I have to ask what has this got to do with C :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, standard C++ doesn't support that type of reflection.  There are some "hacky" ways using macros to create a type-traits-esque template that will use [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) to statically determine whether or not a particular class has a certain data member or member function, but nothing that will actually enumerate every member of a class.

In fact, C++ was designed with a certain philosophy in mind that would make it difficult, if not counter-productive, to support the type of runtime reflection we see in higher-level languages like C#/Java.  See [Why does C++ not have reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359237/why-does-c-not-have-reflection/359462#359462) for a thorough discussion on this issue.

Comment: Shoot.  Another reason why Java is king for non OS/low level stuff

Comment: @Carlo del Mundo: Actually most people see this as a plus. Though reflection is really useful for building developers tools. In real code it is not that useful and often leads to horrible to maintain code (of course there are always exceptions).

Comment: @Martin, true, but I would like to see better support for *compile-time* reflection, which could help enhance template library designs.  Regardless, I think the best use-case of reflection is for implementing generic serialization functions.

Comment: For example, imagine a meta-function that used recursive template instantiation to iterate over all data members in a class.  This would allow the compiler to generically generate serialization functions for any class, without any of the runtime overhead necessitated by Java-style reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is called Reflection. This is not easy to do in C / C++:
http://www.garret.ru/cppreflection/docs/reflect.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really want to write "c++" code with reflection you can look at what [`ROOT`](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) does with `cint` and the `makecint` code-generator. But this probably isn't what you really want to do...