# Compile time dynamic function call

Tags: c++, macros, sfinae, compile-time

Not sure the title highlights my goal.

Can I dynamically call a method at compile time ?
For example:

```
int CallMethod(string methodName, string methodArg)
{
    Foo foo;
    return foo.#methodName(methodArg);
}

CallMethod("getValue", "test"); // This would attempt to call on a Foo instance, method getValue with argument "test" -- foo.getValue("test");
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, use templates or macros.

Comment: Is your function name going to be compile time string literal like you posted in your example or is it going to be read from file/ entered by user etc?

Comment: @Karthik T : string literal

Comment: In that case @YochaiTimmer's will work perfectly for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a Macro:

```
#define CallMethod(methodName, var) { Foo foo; foo.##methodName(var); }
```

in main function:

```
CallMethod(foo,"test");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) and is [not available natively in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359237/why-does-c-not-have-reflection)

If you have a limited number of possible values for `methodName` you could build a Lookup table which calls the appropriate function based on `methodName` but you cannot call arbitrary functions with this system.

This could either be a std::map as @PaperBirdMaster suggests or a giant set of `if-else` checks. But this is not true Reflection, just a crude illusion of the same.

Comment: The only approach I can think about to achieve the OP requeriments is to create a map with string and member function pointers... but it isn't reflection at all

Comment: Is is possible to achieve what I'm trying to do with the help of boost extensions ? Could you give me a reflection example using boost if that is possible ? thanks!

Comment: It's not reflection if it's at compile time.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer True if it is a string literal he can try your suggestion, it should work perfectly, I would just enclose it in `{}` though. If he wants to control function name dynamically however..