# is there any easy way to find structure members size in for loop

Tags: c, structure, sizeof

```
enum
{
    ARRAY1,
    ARRAY2,
    ARRAY3,
    ARRAY4,
    ARRAY5,
    STMEMBERCOUNT
};
```

STMEMBERCOUNT shows that the member list in to the structure

```
typedef struct {
   char array1[26];
   char array2[31];
   char array3[31];
   char array4[11];
   char array5[11];
}ST_ARRAY;


main()
{
    int i;
    int sizeofmember[STMEMBERCOUNT];

    for(i = 0; i < STMEMBERCOUNT; i++)
    {
        sizeofmember[i] = ???????
    }
}
```

so that my array can be filled as

```
sizeofmember[0] = 26
sizeofmember[1] = 31
sizeofmember[2] = 31
sizeofmember[3] = 11
sizeofmember[4] = 11
```

Comment: Despite several question marks... I don't see a question here.

Comment: are you trying to iterate over the members of an `enum` ? Anyway I suggest to change your first part of the `enum` definition in `ARRAY1 = 0,`

Comment: sizeof() will only work if i put all Question marks like example:

Comment: what is the point of `ST_ARRAY` anyway ? What kind of role is playing in your business logic ?

Comment: @JonahNelson: man can you provide an example that fill sizeofmember variable with the sizeof all member in structure using for loop

Comment: Enumeration of fields at runtime is a feature of reflection. Neither C nor C++ has builtin support for that. http://stackoverflow.com/q/359237/1175253 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/41453/1175253 . You could use a C++11 tuple and a static (compile time) iteration.

Comment: sizeofmember[0] = 26 // sizeof(ST_ARRAY.array1)
sizeofmember[1] = 31 // sizeof(ST_ARRAY.array2)
sizeofmember[2] = 31 // sizeof(ST_ARRAY.array3)
sizeofmember[3] = 11 // sizeof(ST_ARRAY.array4)
sizeofmember[4] = 11 // sizeof(ST_ARRAY.array5)

Comment: @JonahNelson i want all individual ST_ARRAY structure member size by loop iteration and fill it to sizeofmember variable, or is there any way to jump between the members of the structure by use of pointer

Comment: @user2485710 i am posting first time so forget the line  just want is individual ST_ARRAY structure member size by loop iteration and fill it to sizeofmember variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to iterate over members of a struct or enum.

This is not possible in C/C++ mainly because a C program is compiled. The languages that allow to iterate over members usually have the programs interpreted or run in a virtual machine or in a runtime environment, where you can more easily have runtime information about your structures.

Comment: i want to iterate on structure members only enum is just to find the number of iteration