# Delphi use reflection in a class procedure for the getting dynamic class type

Tags: delphi, reflection, rtti

I want use reflection on the current class inside a class procedure/function (static method). How can I do without using the "Self" keyword? And without harcode the class name: this procedure should be override in the descendants.

```
class procedure AAA.SetTableAndSequence;
var
c : TRttiContext;
t : TRttiType;
begin
  c := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    t := c.GetType(Self.ClassType);
    ...
  finally
   c.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: FWIW, the try/finally is pointless here. `TRttiContext` is not a class. Just use `c` directly. It auto-initializes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ClassInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.TObject.ClassInfo) and [`GetType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Rtti.TRttiContext.GetType):

```
class procedure AAA.SetTableAndSequence;
var
  c: TRttiContext;
  t: TRttiType;
begin
  t := c.GetType(ClassInfo);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: What exactly is the value returned by `ClassInfo`? Is it the same thing that a `TypeInfo` would return? Oh and thanks for pointing out that my now deleted answer was bogus.

Comment: Yes, the VMT contains a field to the TypeInfo of a class (`vmtTypeInfo` slot) which is returned by the `ClassInfo` class function.