# I defined an templated class. Can I see the (source) code that occurs after it is instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, inline

C++ I defined an templated class.

I'd like to see source code that results when the class is instantiated. For example, imagine I have a class like `std::vector` from the standard library:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector { ... } // this is in the .h and .inl
```

Then I instantiate it

```
vector<int> v = new vector<int>();
```

Can I see the inlined code that the compiler will create?

Comment: The compiler doesn't actually create source code in text form for each template instantiation - so no, you can't see it. Templates are not macros.

Comment: There's no source code, template instantiation isn't a "text-only" step

Comment: `class Vector` c++ is a case sensitive language!

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/359237 Carefully read the accepted answer.

Comment: in some c++ talk (maybe going native) Chandler Carruth stated that there is progress done in a tool that partially instantiates templates based on clang/llvm

Answer (score 0):

There's no source code, template instantiation isn't a text-replace step. To inspect the generated code you should use a disassembler/debugger or dump (if the compiler supports it) the generated code. Template instantiation is a compilation step and although it can get pretty complex, it generates code and not text.

Macros undergo a process similar to what you described: they're processed in the *pre-processing* stage and they're just plain text substitutions