# A variable (or an attribute) can be equal to a type?

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++17, class-template

I wanted to know if a variable can be equal to a type (here it's the `magic_type`)

```
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
class C
{
public:
   magic_type t;
   t list;
   T data;

   C(void)
   {
      if (typeid(data) == typeid(int))
         t = float; // so typeid(list) = typedid(float)
      else
         t = int; // and typeid(list) = typedid(int)
   }
};
```

Comment: Types don't exist per se at runtime. Can you elaborate on why you need "type variables" and why templates don't meet your requirements?

Comment: A variable cannot be equal to a type.  The *type* is a property of the variable, mainly used by the compiler.

Comment: Not sure what the use case would be, but if you want to set a flag indicating what type a variable is, you can use an enum. Something like: `enum VariableTypes { FLOAT, INT }` and declare `t` of type `enum VariableTypes`.

Comment: ah okay too bad thanks ^^

Comment: You can use templates for functions as well.  You can also overload functions (without templates).  The compiler will pick the correct function based on the parameter types.

Comment: See also: [Why does C++ not have reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359237)

Comment: You don't need `magic_type t;` because you already have it:  `T`.  Change `t list;` to `T list;`.  In C++, an empty parameter list is idiomatically given as `C()` rather than `C(void)`.

Comment: do you really want `t` to be `float` when `T` is `int` or is this a typo?

Comment: Isn't the answer [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info)? (But also don't do this, use `std::conditional` and templates)

Answer (score 6):

If you want the `magic_type` be `float` when `T == int` and otherwise `float`, use [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional). This will resolve the `magic_type` at compile time.

In order to check whether two types are the same, you could use [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). Include `<type_traits>`, for both of the trait's usage.

```
#include <type_traits>  // std::conditional_t, std::is_same_v

template<typename T>
class C
{
   // type alias
   using magic_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, float, int>;

   magic_type t;  // now `magic_type` == `float` if `T` == `int`, otherwise `float`
   T data;

public:       
   // ... code
};
```

Comment: All right, thank you very much. ^^
And if I have other conditions, how can I add them if(typeid(data) == typeid(string)), if(typeid(data) == typeid(bool)), etc.?

Comment: @user13286774 The same way demonstrated above. For example for `std::string`, you could  `std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::string>, /* true type*/, /*false type*/>;`

Comment: Yeah i get it ^^. But can we use more than two types ?

Comment: @user13286774 *use more than two types* for example? Do you mean checking more types together: `using magic_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, bool>, float, int>;`?

Answer (score 2):

A general way to do this without nesting and keeping the logic code more familiar is with an `if constexpr` helper:

```
// Not needed if you know you can default-construct every type.
template<typename T>
struct type_t {
    using type = T;
};

static auto get_list_type() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        return type_t<float>{};
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) {
        return type_t<int>{};
    } else if constexpr (...) {
         return ...;
    } else {
        return ...;
    }
}

typename decltype(get_list_type())::type list; // no typename in C++20
```

If you're so inclined, there are also a couple compile-time `switch` libraries out there.