# Extract the variable name of a pointer as a string

Tags: c++

I have a pointer to an `int` object.

```
   int x = 10;
   int *ptr;
   ptr = &x;
```

I want to write a function `GetString(int *ptr)` which would return me the string `ptr`. How do I do that in C++?

Comment: u can't. but u can use map if there are many pointers u want to deal with in this way or a pair if there is only one.

Comment: can you give an example usage?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a direct way to extract a variable's string name in C++. The language has only rudimentary reflection features, see the [type_traits standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) and SO post [Why does C++ not have reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359237/why-does-c-not-have-reflection).

But you *can* use preprocessor stringification `#` to hack something similar: define

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
```

then the preprocessor substitutes `STRINGIFY(ptr)` with the string `"ptr"`.

Note: if you want to stringify the result of a macro expansion [use two levels of macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/Stringification.html).

Comment: I tried this approach, it does work for pointers. The issue is (and that is my fault that the question doesn't reflect the point) that I actually wanted to define a function like this:
```string GetVariableName(int *ptr){
string str = STRINGIFY(ptr);
return str;}```
When I do this and then use ```int *alphabeta; GetVariableName(alphabeta);```, it still returns the string ```'ptr'```. It makes sense why the output is this way, but then it renders the STRINGIFY approach moot for me, I think. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way in C++ to accomplish this with a function. The closest you can do is make `GetVariableName` itself the "STRINGIFY" macro, or use an approach like asmmo suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

const std::string& getString(int  *ptr, const std::map<int*, std::string>& mp){
    return mp.find(ptr)->second;

}

int main()
{
    std::map<int* , std::string> mp;

    int x = 10;
    mp.insert({&x, "ptr1"});

    int y = 9;
    mp.insert({&y, "ptr2"});

    std::cout << getString(&y, mp);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nqe6dh)