# How to get/print the name/identifier of an array in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a function and I want to print the name/identifier of the array I pass as an argument.

```
void printArrayElements(int num[], int size){
 cout << "Array name: " << num << endl;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    cout << "Array elements: " << num[i] << endl;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

When I pass (test,5) and (cool,10) as an argument,

```
int main(){

int test[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int cool[10] = {4,1,2,4,5,3,7,4,2,7};
printArrayElements(test,5);
printArrayElements(cool,10);
```

}

The result I get is,

[Terminal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jEtc.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jEtc.png

I want the name of the array cool and jess to be printed after "Array name:" not  0x61ff0c and  0x61fee4.

```
cout << "Array name: " << num << endl;
```

By this, I intend to print the identifier of the array passed into the function as an argument. Its not working. How do I make that happen?

Comment: That's not possible in c++.

Comment: I'm afraid you chose the wrong language for this kind of task. See [Why does C++ not have reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359237/why-does-c-not-have-reflection)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the function in a macro, and use the preprocessor to get the variable name as a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define printArray(x, y) printArrayElements((#x), x, y)

void printArrayElements(std::string name, int num[], int size){
    std::cout << "Array name: " << name << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        std::cout << "Array elements: " << num[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int test[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int cool[10] = {4,1,2,4,5,3,7,4,2,7};

    printArray(test, 5);
    printArray(cool, 10);
}
```

Comment: Btw, to make this code build and run without error, also requires: `#include <iostream>`
`#include <string>` in the very beginning.

Comment: Macros are evil... ...but still allow little nice tricks like [this on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a9d5e9a14281daf). ;-)

Comment: One part of the evilness is that this has now redefined all `printArray` functions of all classes in every namespace. To save some typing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with vanilla C++ at the moment, but you can use the preprocesser to do it:

```
#define PRINTNAME(name) (std::cout << "name" << ":" << (#name) << std::endl)
```