# How to get information about "current type" inside of a struct/class?

Tags: c++, macros

Is it possible to get "type of the current `struct`" inside of the `struct`?
For example, I want to do something like this:

```
struct foobar {
  int x, y;

  bool operator==(const THIS_TYPE& other) const  /*  What should I put here instead of THIS_TYPE? */
  {
    return x==other.x && y==other.y;
  }
}
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
struct foobar {
  int x, y;

  template<typename T>
  bool operator==(const T& t) const
  {
    decltype (*this)& other = t; /* We can use `this` here, so we can get "current type"*/
    return x==other.x && y==other.y;
  }
}
```

but it looks ugly, requires support of the latest C++ Standard, and MSVC connot compile it (it crashes with "an internal error").

Actually, I just want to write some preprocessor macros to auto-generate functions like `operator==`:

```
struct foobar {
  int x, y;
  GEN_COMPARE_FUNC(x, y);
}

struct some_info {
  double len;
  double age;
  int rank;
  GEN_COMPARE_FUNC(len, age, rank);
}
```

But I need to know "current type" inside of the macro.

Comment: Why not just make your macro GEN_COMPARE_FUNC(foobar, x, y) instead?

Comment: @ForEveR via `Variadic Macros`. It's supported by GCC and MSVC, so it's enough for me.

Comment: By using a templated `bool operator==`, you may accidentally make it possible to compare two types where it doesn't make sense for them to be comparable.

Comment: @Rollie, You're right, it can be implemented this way, of course. But I need to check that there is no other solutions.

Comment: I think the closest you can get is by typedefing a 'curType' in each class you want to use the macros in, so `typedef foobar curType;`, and then in the macros, `bool operator==(const curType & _rhs) const {...}`

Comment: Why not send type in define? I.e. GEN_OP(foobar, x, y) ?

Comment: Why not make your comparison operatior a free function?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use somethink like this.

```
#define GEN_COMPARE_FUNC(type, x, y)\
template<typename type>\
bool operator ==(const type& t) const\
{\
    return this->x == t.x && this->y == t.y;\
}

struct Foo
{
    int x, y;
    GEN_COMPARE_FUNC(Foo, x, y);
};
```

I have no idea, how use var. macro-pars in this way (we need to go throw the params and compare each par from this and from t, i have no idea, how expand params in macro).

Answer (score 0):

This stack-overflow URL states that the boost libraries can compute the type of an expression, but C/C++ by itself cannot:

[Getting name and type of a struct field from its object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514401/getting-name-and-type-of-a-struct-field-from-its-object)

Someone asked a similar question also:

[How can I add reflection to a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

To start using typeof include the typeof header:

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
```

To deduce the type of an expression at compile time use the BOOST_TYPEOF macro:

```
namespace ex1
{
    typedef BOOST_TYPEOF(1 + 0.5) type;

    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((is_same<type, double>::value));
}
```

Comment: C++11 can. typedef decltype(1 + 0.5) type;