# C++ "if then else" template substitution

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement

I would like to declare a template as follows:

```
template <typename T>
{ 
  if objects of class T have method foo(), then 
   const int k=1
  else 
   if class has a static const int L then
    const int k=L
   else 
    const int k=0;


}
```

How can I do this? In general, I would like a mechanism for setting static consts
based on properties of T (or typedef defined inside T).

Comment: @Jan,  good point of reminding me to pull back my code snippet :)

Comment: @Jan: I did just now. Sometimes I forget to click the arrow even if I have identified a valid answer. I realize its unfair to the responders - I will try to be better about it.

Comment: 1. It's about giving back; 2. People here put a lot of time and effort into their answers. The OP is well-advised to show respect for that; 3. If someone comes across the question in the future, they find the best answer right away and don't have to assume; 4. It's just how this site works.

Comment: @duli: Even though you probably don't, if you know all the functions you can make a text file and check to see what objects functions contain by making the constructor of a 'class T' write into a text indicating what objects contain what.

Comment: @Jan - "If someone comes across the question in the future, they find the best answer right away and don't have to assume." That actually IS an assumption and a rather poor one at that.  More than a few times I've seen the poster accept incorrect answers.

Comment: Usually, the best answers is the one with the most upvotes, and *not* necessarily the accepted one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outer part is of course quite easy.  Use boost::mpl::if_ to decide which int_ type to return from your metafunction and then access the value in it.  No big deal.

The part where you try to find out if type X has a function f() is still fairly straight forward but unfortunately you'll not find a generic answer.  Every time you need this kind of inspection you'll have to write a custom metafunction to find it out.  Use SFINAE:

```
  template < typename T >
  struct has_foo
  {
    typedef char (&no)  [1];
    typedef char (&yes) [2];

    template < void (T::*)() >
    struct dummy {};

    template < typename S >
    static yes check( dummy<&S::foo> *);

    template < typename S >
    static no check( ... );

    enum { value = sizeof(check<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes)  };
  };
```

Edit: Oh, and create a checker for your static const L with BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX()

Comment: Nice, I'll keep this snipet around.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say answer in current form, because problem domain isn't clear.

Still, you could try using the [type traits technique](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442), which enhances your templated class by adding parameters specific to only objects which have type `T`.

*I'm pretty sure, that using type traits could solve your problems, still, using them and writing / making old routines generic could sometimes get tricky.*

Answer (score 0):

Using boost's [enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) some of such functionality can be implemented using traits. But since C++ lacks reflection questions like "does this class contains this method/member?" are not easy to [resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

Comment: Too bad I wasn't around at the time to give the poster a useful answer.  I posted it now.