# Get list of available data member from a POD struct in C++

Tags: c++

the question can sound a bit unusual. Let's take a POD struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
   int myInt;
   double myDouble;
   AnotherPOD* myPointer;
};
```

The compiler knows the list of available data members. Do you know any way to get list of data member name (and type) either at compile time (better) or at run time?

I have a huge amount of POD structs and I would like to automate the creation of operator<<.

I know I could create a parser for the header files, create some files and compile those. However, I am sure the compiler has already had this information and I would like to exploit it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add reflection to a C++ application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

Comment: You could probably get something working using tricky templates and adding some macros like `REGISTER_MEMBER(MyStruct::myInt)`.  But the existing tools pointed out by answers below would probably be less painful.

Comment: Are you outputting in binary or text?  I assume you're probably outputting text since you're using operator<<, but in case you're not, there's a very simple solution.

Comment: I need the text version, however I am curious. Which is the very simple solution suitable for binary?

Answer (score 5):

[BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT](http://boost-spirit.com/dl_more/fusion_v2/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/extension/macros/adapt_struct.html) introduces compile-time reflection (which is awesome).

It is up to you to map this to run-time reflection of course, and it won't be too easy, but it is possible in this direction, while it would not be in the reverse :)

Comment: Liked this solution. Posted the detailed code here: [C++ iterate into nested struct field with boost fusion adapt_struct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12084781/362754)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any way to do what you want directly, but you might want to take a look at clang, which is a compiler front-end implementation that you can make use of to do other things:

http://clang.llvm.org

I guess you'd then be able to traverse the abstract syntax tree it creates and get at the information you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Well, standard C++ compilers can't do that, they lack reflection capabilities.

Sounds like a task for a code generator. So either use a toolkit to extract these informations from the headers or generate both headers and serialization functions from another source. Just make sure you [do not repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Code generation sure sounds like the best way here, that way you only have to write the `operator<<` functions once and existing headers do not have to change.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid but C++ doesn't support reflection. You can use [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) to achieve a restricted form of reflection at compile time.