# Is there a way to enumerate all data members of a struct?

Tags: c++

I know it is possible to check whether a specific data member exists, but is it also possible to enumerate them all?

EDIT: I want to enumerate them in code, compile time is ok.

Comment: In what context? The compiler will know, and debug symbols will contain that sort of information. But you probably can't access either in your source code...

Comment: what do you mean when you say "enumerate"? Do you want to be able to process it one after another, like in array, even if they have different types?

Comment: I've lost count of the number of times this has been asked. Do you not _search_?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167030/get-list-of-available-data-member-from-a-pod-struct-in-c?rq=1

Comment: The subject you are talking about is "reflection".  The C++ language does not offer *reflection*, but you may come up with your own design.  In any case, search the web for "stackoverflow c++ reflection"