# Checking whether a function (not a method) exists in c++11 via templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae

So with SFINAE and c++11, it is possible to implement two different template functions based on whether one of the template parameters can be substituted.

For example

```
struct Boo{
   void saySomething(){ cout << "Boo!" << endl; }
};

template<class X>
void makeitdosomething(decltype(&X::saySomething), X x){
   x.saySomething();
}

template<class X>
void makeitsaysomething(int whatever, X x){
    cout << "It can't say anything!" << endl;
}


int main(){
   makeitsaysomething(3);
   makeitsaysomething(Boo());
}
```

or something along that line.

My question is.. how does one do the same thing, but for non-member functions?

In particular I'm trying to check if there's such thing as an:

```
operator<<(std::ostream& os, X& whateverclass);
```

that exists. Is it possible to test it?

edit: the question is different to : [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288) in that I'm trying to see whether a function exists, not a method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a function's existence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Answer (score 8):

I find the `void_t` trick to be usually preferable to the traditional SFINAE method shown in the other answer.

```
template<class...> using void_t = void; // now in the C++17 working paper!
// GCC <= 4.9 workaround:
// template<class...> struct voider { using type = void; };
// template<class... T> using void_t = typename voider<T...>::type;

template<class, class = void>
struct is_ostreamable : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_ostreamable<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() <<
                                         std::declval<T>())>> : std::true_type {};
```

The partial specialization is selected if and only if the expression is well-formed.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3b2eb37b46fff50).
Note that the `&` in `std::declval<std::ostream&>()` is important, because otherwise `std::declval<std::ostream>()` is an rvalue and you'll get `ostream`'s catchall rvalue stream insertion operator, and report that everything is streamable.

The above code checks for an `operator<<` that can accept a `T` rvalue . If you want to check for one that accepts an lvalue `T`, then use `std::declval<T&>()`.

Answer (score 4):

Using SFINAE, it's possible like this:

```
template <typename T>
class has_ostream_lshift
{
  struct no {};

  template <typename T2>
  static decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T2>()) test(int);

  template <typename T2>
  static no test(...);

public:
  enum { value = ! std::is_same<no, decltype(test<T>(0))>::value};
};
```

Comment: `std::declval<std::ostream &>()`. That `&` is important.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `void_t`. With `decltype` and comma separator, it's possible like this:

```
template <class, class = void> struct is_ostreamable : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_ostreamable<
    T, decltype(std::declval<std::ostream &>() << std::declval<T>(), void())>
    : std::true_type {};
```