# C++ equivalent of Python getattr

Tags: c++, python, serialization, boost, getattr

In python, there is a function called getattr which would look like this:

```
class MyObject():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xyz = 4

obj = MyObject()
getattr(obj, 'xyz')
```

where the call to getattr would return 4.

Is there a similar way to do this in C++ (Not Visual C++)?

Are there any libraries that have this functionality where I can lookup an object's member variables using a string?

I am trying to find a way to look up public data members in a C++ class that I cannot change. So I cannot use a map to map string literals to values. Maybe like an 'unstringify' with macros?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application

Comment: Well you _could_ write C/C++ and work against the python VM and create python objects :) (just kidding! just kidding!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are asking for is commonly referred to as **Introspection**.

The C++ language does not support introspection by itself. You can emulate it, but that is the extent of it.

There is also another issue in the API you propose: how would you formulate the return type of your method ? There *is* a `boost::any` class that would be suitable to store the item, but you would not be able to anything useful with it if you do not know its type anyway.

Comment: Yes, introspection, that is what I am looking for. As far as the type, I am not too worried as all the data members are int or double values. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Nothing like this exists in standard C++. Consider how a struct or class actually works:

```
struct MyStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

Assuming that an `int` is 32 bits in size, then the location of `MyStruct`'s `b` is always 4 bytes away from the location of `a`. That *offset* arithmetic is handled by the compiler in advance. It's why C is so fast for accessing member data: there is no runtime look-up!

So if I wanted to lookup `"b"` at runtime, I'd have to find where that is in the struct. And to do that, the compiler would have to generate an offset table to store somewhere in the code. That's a lot of overhead for a language that's meant to not have any hidden inefficiencies.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none that I know of. This would require special support from a compiler because current compilers do not store any sort of metadata that would be required for this sort of reflection

Comment: Um, well, unless you care to use debug symbols. :)

Comment: Agreed, but I doubt that this would ever be implemented