# Passing a "full" string array to a function

Tags: c++

I was trying to pass `myStringArray` to a function in the following code.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int loopy(auto someString){
    for (auto Word : someString){
        cout << "In " << __func__ << " word is " << Word << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    string myStringArray[] = {"abc","def", "xyz", "meh" };
    for (auto Word: myStringArray){
        cout << "In " << __func__ << " word is " << Word << endl;
    }
    loopy(*myStringArray);
    return 0;
}
```

The o/p I see is:

```
$ ./a.out 
In main word is abc
In main word is def
In main word is xyz
In main word is meh
In loopy word is a // <<-- this
In loopy word is b // <<--this 
In loopy word is c // <<--this
```

As you can see, the `loopy` function only does see the 1st word of the string array(?) that I am passing.

What am I doing wrong, and what's the correct way to pass these C++ nuances to functions?  Thanks!

Comment: Name of array is treated as pointer to its first item, so by `loopy(*myStringArray)` you are passing first string into loopy function, not array.

Comment: I guess you're coming from a python background

Comment: @AndrewScott:  yes, on my day 4 with C++, Python/C->Go->C++  has been my route. C++ is both daunting and interesting.

Comment: `*myStringArray` is the same as `myStringArray[0]`, which is a `std::string` - specifically, the string `"abc"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native array arguments work differently than other containers in C++.

The best way to implement your code using C++ will be to use `std::vector`:

```
int loopy(auto &someString){
    for (auto Word : someString){
        std::cout << "In " << __func__ << " word is " << Word << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> myStringArray = {"abc","def", "xyz", "meh" };
    for (auto Word : myStringArray){
        std::cout << "In " << __func__ << " word is " << Word << std::endl;
    }
    loopy(myStringArray);
    return 0;
}
```

See the minor differences:

- We use `std::vector` to keep the strings
- `loopy` accepts a reference to the original `std::vector`

Comment: I wouldn't say these are minor differences :)

Comment: @Daniel -Trugman,   thank you. I guess half the battle is knowing which container to use. [How](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408315/generating-class-datamembers-from-a-vector#comment99414206_56408315) can I know/determine which one to use?

Comment: @struggling_learner, generally speaking about programming, I would suggest learning one or two courses about data structures. Regarding C++, I would generally use [standard library containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)