# struct to/from std::tuple conversion

Tags: c++, c++17

Assuming I have `struct` and `std::tuple` with same type layout:

```
struct MyStruct { int i; bool b; double d; }
using MyTuple = std::tuple<int,bool,double>;
```

Is there any standartized way to cast one to another?

P.S. I know that trivial memory copying can do the trick, but it is alignment and implementation dependent

Comment: "*P.S. I know that trivial memory copying can do the trick*" `std::tuple<>` has no guarantees about triviality, so memory copying here would be UB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TMP: how to write template code which converts any struct into a tuple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889934/tmp-how-to-write-template-code-which-converts-any-struct-into-a-tuple)

Comment: @ildjarn it actually has no guarantees even about order in which elements are stored internally. Also agressive space optimisations of user-defined classes with padding and empty classes can ruin your day too.

Comment: `memcpy` sounds like a terrible idea here...

Comment: There is a library ['magic_get'](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) that does introspection on structs.

Comment: I updated my solution to be valid even if the members are not default-constructible.

Comment: @IlyaPopov, that library seems pretty amazing, I still don't understand how is it possible that they achieve that level of introspection. (My best guess is that uses some clever macro disguissed in `struct`)

Comment: @alfC As far as I understand they use the same trick as in Yakk's answer.

Comment: Update: that trick obviously can only be used in C++17 mode. In C++14 mode they use something else. If I remember correctly, the author once explained how it works on boost.devel mailing list, but it seems to be down today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no automatic way to do that, BUT an alternative is adapt the struct to Boost.Fusion sequence. You do this once and for all for each new class.

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
...
struct MyStruct { int i; bool b; double d; }

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    MyStruct,
    (int, i)
    (bool, b)
    (double, d)
)
```

The use `MyStruct` as if it where a Fusion.Sequence (it fits generically almost everywhere you already use `std::tuple<...>`, if you make those functions generic.) As a bonus you will not need to copy your data members at all.

If you *really* need to convert to `std::tuple`, after "Fusion-adapting" you can do this:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/transformation/zip.hpp>
...
auto to_tuple(MyStruct const& ms){
   std::tuple<int, bool, double> ret;
   auto z = zip(ret, ms);
   boost::fusion::for_each(z, [](auto& ze){get<0>(ze) = get<1>(ze);});
   // or use boost::fusion::copy
   return ret;
}
```

The truth is that `std::tuple` is a half-backed feature. It is like having STD containers and no algorithms. Fortunatelly we have `#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>` that allows us to do amazing things.

Full code:

By including the `std_tuple.hpp` header from Boost.Fusion `std::tuple` is automatically adapted to a Boost.Fusion sequence, thus the following is possible by using Boost.Fusion as a bridge between your struct and `std::tuple`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/auxiliary/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>

struct foo
{
  std::string a, b, c;
  int d, e, f;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    foo,
    (std::string, a)
    (std::string, b)
    (std::string, c)
    (int, d)
    (int, e)
    (int, f)
)

template<std::size_t...Is, class Tup>
foo to_foo_aux(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tup&& tup) {
  using std::get;
  return {get<Is>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))...};
}
template<class Tup>
foo to_foo(Tup&& tup) {
  using T=std::remove_reference_t<Tup>;
  return to_foo_aux(
    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>{}>{},
    std::forward<Tup>(tup)
  );
}

template<std::size_t...Is>
auto to_tuple_aux( std::index_sequence<Is...>, foo const& f ) {
  using boost::fusion::at_c;
  return std::make_tuple(at_c<Is>(f)...);
}
auto to_tuple(foo const& f){
  using T=std::remove_reference_t<foo>;
  return to_tuple_aux(
    std::make_index_sequence<boost::fusion::result_of::size<foo>::type::value>{},
    f
  );    
}

int main(){


    foo f{ "Hello", "World", "!", 1, 2, 3 };

    std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string, int, int, int> dest = to_tuple(f);
    // boost::fusion::copy(f, dest); // also valid  but less general than constructor

    std::cout << std::get<0>(dest) << ' ' << std::get<1>(dest) << std::get<2>(dest) << std::endl;
    std::cout << at_c<0>(dest) << ' ' << at_c<1>(dest) << at_c<2>(dest) << std::endl; // same as above

    foo f2 = to_foo(dest);

    std::cout << at_c<0>(f2) << ' ' << at_c<1>(f2) << at_c<2>(f2) << std::endl;
}
```

---

I **will not** recommend `reinterpret_cast<std::tuple<...>&>(mystructinstance.i)` because that will result in negative votes and it is not portable.

Comment: "*I __will not__ recommend `reinterpret_cast<std::tuple<...>&>(mystructinstance.i)` because that will result in negative votes and it is not portable.*" You shouldn't recommend it because it's downright _illegal_, not just because you'll get downvoted. ;-] +1 for mentioning Fusion though!

Comment: Not only is it downright illegal, there's no guarantee that it would work across all implementations. Or even some implementations.

Comment: @ildjam I am a bit demagogue today (it is the current trend), I worry more about downvotes than C++ legality. :)

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes, that is why I said "it is not portable" even if it works in some system.

Comment: If you include the boost fusion std_tuple header, it adapts the `std::tuple` so that you can simply call `boost::fusion::copy()` to copy from the adapted structure to `std::tuple`... you don' need to use your custom iteration.. In effect, it promotes `std::tuple` to a fusion sequence, so copy in either direction should be possible (and it's smart enough to handle repeated types..)

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the example for copy, I think it makes this answer complete - if you feel it's irrelevant, remove it..

Comment: @Nim, yes, thank you. I was sure that there was a `copy` algorithm` but I couldn't find it in the main manual. It was in the auxiliary section http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/auxiliary/functions/copy.html . What I really didn't figure out yet, how to generate the struct from the tuple if the elements are not default constructible, perhaps there is no way.

Comment: @Nim, I figured out how to do it even if the member types are not default constructible. `boost::fusion::copy` can be used but it is not necessary.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer since as I'm also trying to convert structs to tuple choosing which elements should be moved to the resultant tuple.

Answer (score 22):

We can use structured bindings to convert a struct into a tuple with a bit of work.

Struct-to-tuple is very awkward.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct to_tuple_t;

template<>
struct to_tuple_t<3> {
  template<class S>
  auto operator()(S&& s)const {
    auto[e0,e1,e2]=std::forward<S>(s);
    return std::make_tuple(e0, e1, e2);
  }
};
```

Now, write a `to_tuple_t` for each size you want to support.  This gets tedious.  Sadly I know of no way to introduce a parameter pack there.

```
template<std::size_t N, class S>
auto to_tuple(S&& s) {
  return to_tuple_t<N>{}(std::forward<S>(s));
}
```

I know of no way to calculate the value of `N` required either.  So you'd have to type the `3` in `auto t = to_tuple<3>(my_struct);` when you call it.

I am not a master of structured bindings.  There is probably a `&&` or `&` or a decltype that would permit perfect forwarding on these lines:

```
    auto[e0,e1,e2]=std::forward<S>(s);
    return std::make_tuple(e0, e1, e2);
```

but without a compiler to play with, I'll be conservative and make redundant copies.

---

Converting a tuple into a struct is easy:

```
template<class S, std::size_t...Is, class Tup>
S to_struct( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tup&& tup ) {
  using std::get;
  return {get<Is>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))...};
}
template<class S, class Tup>
S to_struct( Tup&&tup ) {
  using T=std::remove_reference_t<Tup>;

  return to_struct(
    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>{}>{},
    std::forward<Tup>(tup)
  );
}
```

SFINAE support based off `tuple_size` might be good for `to_struct`.

The above code works with all tuple-likes, like `std::pair`, `std::array`, and anything you custom-code to support structured bindings (`tuple_size` and `get<I>`).

---

Amusingly,

```
std::array<int, 3> arr{1,2,3};
auto t = to_tuple<3>(arr);
```

works and returns a tuple with 3 elements, as `to_tuple` is based on structured bindings, which work with tuple-likes as input.

`to_array` is another possibility in this family.

Comment: @rusty I do not like the aliasing violations in that.  Why reinterpret cast into a pointer to something that it isn't?  UB should have massive payoff before even considering it.

Comment: *"I know of no way to calculate the value of N required either"*, upper limit is `sizeof(T)`, to you can test aggregate initialization up to that limit, something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed39db7ae090e3b7).

Comment: @Jarod42 I think yours breaks with enough elements of no unique address.  But yes, that is really close.

Comment: [Indeed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fe77a07f6fad8a5)...

Comment: *"I know of no way to calculate the value of N required"* I am certain you know already but here is a way to do it for everyone else: [arity of aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35463646/2712726) . This works for simple structs in C++14 but C++17 even allows the members of the aggregates to be inherited. Functions will not be counted. It's as close to a miracle as you can get in C++. In C++20 there are simpler ways, simpler, not simple.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any standartized way to cast one to another?

There is no way to "cast" the one to the other.

The easiest may be to use a [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to pack the tuple out into the `struct`;

```
struct MyStruct { int i; bool b; double d; };
using MyTuple = std::tuple<int,bool,double>;

auto t = std::make_tuple(42, true, 5.1);
MyStruct s;

std::tie(s.i, s.b, s.d) = t;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/955b1799801fa040).

You can further wrap this up in higher level macros or "generator" (`make` style) functions, e.g;

```
std::tuple<int, bool, double> from_struct(MyStruct const& src)
{
  return std::make_tuple(src.i, src.b, src.d);
}

MyStruct to_struct(std::tuple<int, bool, double> const& src)
{
  MyStruct s;
  std::tie(s.i, s.b, s.d) = src;
  return s;
}
```

> I know that trivial memory copying can do the trick, but it is alignment and implementation dependent?

You mention the "trivial memory copy" would work - only for copying the individual members. So basically, a `memcpy` of the entire structure to the `tuple` and vice-versa is not going to always behave as you expect (if ever); the memory layout of a `tuple` is not standardised. If it does work, it is highly dependent on the implementation.

Comment: I am looking for a more general solution. Which at least doesn't require referring to every struct member.

Comment: All the solutions I've seen over the years that require individual access to members (i.e. referring to each one), do just that (often using macros); examples here include boost serialisation etc. The pain can be eased with a scripted implementation, the script can generate the boilerplate code, you can also include this in the build such that it is always correct and up to date for the structures being compiled. Unfortunately there is no standard conversion mapping these things.

Answer (score 5):

Tuple to `struct` conversion is trivial, but backward I think is impossible at current C++ level in general.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

#include <tuple>

namespace details
{

template< typename result_type, typename ...types, std::size_t ...indices >
result_type
make_struct(std::tuple< types... > t, std::index_sequence< indices... >) // &, &&, const && etc.
{
    return {std::get< indices >(t)...};
}

}

template< typename result_type, typename ...types >
result_type
make_struct(std::tuple< types... > t) // &, &&, const && etc.
{
    return details::make_struct< result_type, types... >(t, std::index_sequence_for< types... >{}); // if there is repeated types, then the change for using std::index_sequence_for is trivial
}

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    using S = struct { int a; char b; double c; };
    auto s = make_struct< S >(std::make_tuple(1, '2', 3.0));
    assert(s.a == 1);
    assert(s.b == '2');
    assert(s.c == 3.0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7040d22b107637e0).

Comment: You need to do some dancing with indexes if the types are not distinct.

Comment: @Yakk There is also some proper forwarding of tuple's contents possible..