# C++ Introspection techniques, similar to python

Tags: c++, python, introspection

Are there introspection techniques in C++ like those in python?

For example: I want to get more information about a specific object without going through the header file or referring back to cpp reference.

Am I asking a proper question, or moving the wrong direction here?

**Update:**

Based on the below answers, this answer is related to my question: [How can I add reflection to a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

Comment: Are you referring to Reflection? https://www.google.com/search?q=reflection+in+c%2B%2B

Comment: I don't know about Reflection, may be it is .. I'm talking here from that point of view: being able to iterate over members of a type, enumerate its methods, attributes, and so on.

Comment: Generally "no". The standard compilation model for C++ means that basically none of the type characteristics are retained in the compiled machine code, and thus they are not inspectable at runtime.

Comment: I guess this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application is very related to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ has a built in RTTI system, though it's for the most part horribly worthless. As a result custom introspection used instead.

Introspection in C++ is implemented with two main methods: preprocesing step where you scan cpp files and create a database/generate CPP code; use templating. I wrote some articles on the templating technique [here](http://cecilsunkure.blogspot.com/2012/09/c-reflection-class-metadata-introduction.html).

If you're more interested in just using introspection rather than implementing it, I suggest looking up clReflect, or you can try [cpfg](https://github.com/cpgf/cpgf).

Comment: It seems to be less than straight forward as python does .. I need to consider the stuff you referred to above .. thanks!

Comment: @securecurve Yes it's much more difficult since it is not supported by the language itself.

Comment: Would it be more helpful to use an IDE that does that for me? As manual investigation of objects will be a headache more than a praise .... If you know one or more IDEs that supports intersection (whatever the underlying technique), please let me know ... thanks!

Comment: You may have a look at Qt library with its QObject base class and its metaobject system. It provides discoverable properties and much more, and relies on "moc", a precompiler tool

Answer (score 5):

Python and C++ are radically different languages.  Normally,
almost all of the type information is lost once you've finished
compiling.  About all you can do is ask if an object is
a specific class (using `typeid`), or if it is an instance of
a specific class (using `dynamic_cast`).  In theory, you can
also get the name of the type, using `typeid::name()`, but in
practice, the standard doesn't impose anything useful for the
return value, and some compilers (e.g. g++) don't give you
anything useful.