# How to get the exact type of a pointer in run time for virtual functions?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I am using C++ virtual functions. I have a base class treeNode and two derived classed splitNode and leafNode. some pointers in the splitNodes point to other nodes which may be either splitNode or leafNode. At runtime, how can I check whether the pointer points to a leaf or split node, whithout changing the structure of the nodes (i.e., I don't want to add any new function to them).

Regards

Comment: Heard of `dynamic_cast` or `typeid`?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` works, but is very expensive at runtime.

Comment: No, I don't want to cast it. I want its type at runtime. I am searching about typeid...

Comment: The pointer can point to a split or leaf node. I only want to check what is the real type of the object the pointer points to?

Comment: But why do you need to do that? With a different design you probably don't need to know.

Comment: In a kd-tree, I want to disable a node. As all of my data are saved within leaf nodes, I can set such a ''disabled'' flag in such nodes. During the search in a split node, I want to check if a node is a leaf really, so I can check the flag, or else if the node is a split one, I must continue the search down to the tree

Comment: @RezaMortazavi `virtual bool isLeaf() const`. That's one way to do it better than with a cast/RTTI.

Comment: Then you can have `virtual splitNode::disable()` that calls `disable()` on its children, and a `virtual leafNode::disable()` that sets the flag. No check needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear why you would want to do this, but you can use `dynamic_cast`:

```
treeNode* theNode = ....;
splitNode sNode* = dynamic_cast<splitNode*>(theNode);
bool isSplitNode = sNode != nullptr;
```

or just

```
bool isSplitNode = dynamic_cast<splitNode*>(theNode);
```

You shouldn't have to do this if you are using polymorphism correctly.

Comment: I want to check the type. What do you mean by checking it with null?

Comment: @RezaMortazavi if `theNode` does not point to a `splitNode`, the `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer.

Comment: @RezaMortazavi A `dynamic_cast` on pointers returns a null pointer when it fails (that is, when the object pointed to is not actually of the type you're trying to cast it to).

Answer (score 2):

Implement a virtual GetType method in your base class and override it in subclasses.
This is the most efficient way.

Remember [Open closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). You should take advantage of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `dynamic_cast`, or the [typeid](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/the_typeid_operator.htm) operator.  However, generally this is a very bad idea.  If your virtual function needs to know the exact type of the object, then something is wrong with your design.

If you have this situation:

```
class treeNode
{
  virtual int foo()
  {
    // do some default thing, maybe nothing
  }
};

class splitNode : public treeNode
{
  virtual int foo()
  {
    // do whatever splitNode wants to do
  }
};

class leafNode : public treeNode
{
  virtual int foo()
  {
    // do whatever leafNode wants to do
  }
};
```

and you have a pointer `treeNode *p;` that points to either a `splitNode` or a `leafNode` object, and you call `p->foo()`, then the appropriate version of `foo()` will be called.  That is the whole point of virtual functions.

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application).

Answer (score 0):

Have an enum member for what type it is, or a virtual function that returns the number of child nodes. Personally I would just have one node class with an enum (or null child pointers for leafs) for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the underlying type of a pointer to a [runtime-polymorphic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic) object using the `typeid` operator. Here's an example that fits your described design:

```
struct treeNode
{
};

struct splitNode : treeNode
{
    treeNode* left;
    treeNode* right;
};

struct leafNode : treeNode
{
    bool disabled;
};

void traverse(splitNode* node);
void traverse(leafNode* node);

void traverse(treeNode* node)
{
    if(typeid(*node) == typeid(leafNode))
    {
        return traverse(static_cast<leafNode*>(node));
    }
    return traverse(static_cast<splitNode*>(node));
}
```

Note that `dynamic_cast` does pretty much the same thing.

The performance of `typeid` can be poor compared to storing some form of type-id in the base class and using `static_cast`. Despite that caveat, it's extremely useful for code which isn't performance critical (e.g. most code).