# Is it possible to create a vector of types in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to create a vector of types in c++?

Maybe decltype in c++11 can be used for this?

I need this so that I can iterate over this vector, take the type,
that is the class, and create such an instance.

Comment: At compile time? [boost::mpl::vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html). At run time? Nope.

Comment: You were told in the answers to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639747/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-all-elements-in-a-struct-or-class) that this is not possible.

Comment: If you want reflection, you should use a language that has reflection. C++ does not. Nor does it have type

Comment: I think some more context here would be helpful, where does this "vector of types" come from and what do you want to do with this output class instance?  Are the classes all polymorphic with a common base class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create factory templates:

```
class BaseFactory {
public:
    virtual void* create() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Factory :public BaseFactory {
public:
    T* create() const {
        return new T();
    }
};
```

And store such Factory instances in a Vector. However, I don't see much use of it. To simply store types in a vector, take a look at boost's [MPL vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html).

Comment: `Factory::create()` is not recognized as override, because the return type of `T*` is not the same as `void*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a simple way, but there can be some workarounds. I'm not into C++11 yet (my IDE doesn't support it, and I can't change it ATM), but for old C++, you can use `typeid(a).name()`, where `a` is a variable. You can store the result of the function inside a `vector`, and then create variables using an if-else construction.

Or - if you're gonna only want to initialize variables of your classes, then derive them from a `Base` class, which has a function that returns the class type identifier:

```
class Base{
   int classId;
public:
   Base(){classID=0;};
   virtual int myType(){return classID;};
};

class Derived1: public Base{
public:
   Derived1(){classID=1;};
```

and so on. Then you just create objects using a `switch` statement:

```
vector<int> types;

// Populate the vector somewhere here

for(unsigned int i=0;i<types.size();i++){
   Base* newObject;
   switch(types[i].myType()){
   case 0:
      newObject = new Base;
      break;
   case 1:
      newObject = new Derived;
      break;
   default:
      newObject = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean a "vector of types" -- vectors contain data values, not types, so the question doesn't make a lot of sense.

You can make a tuple of types (a tuple is sort of like a vector for types instead of values):

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int, double, std::string> mytype; // typedef a tuple type
mytype foo(4, 3, 2.0, "hello");   // create an instance
double x = get<3>(foo);           // get a value from that instance
get<2>(foo) = 7;                  // change a value in that instance
```

This is all pretty static, as you can't change the type of a variable dynamically, so once you create an instance of a tuple type, its type (and the number and types of its elements) is fixed.

Comment: Tuples don't store types either. They also store values.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: well, yes, but the question as posed is nonsense.  "Types" are a compile time concept, so "storing" them at runtime makes no sense.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley But can't you deduce type for a certain index of a `std::tuple` (at compile time)?

Comment: Well, it makes sense in some languages. It's not completely unreasonable for someone to suspect that it might also make sense in C++.  We can't expect everyone who asks a question about C++ to already be an expert in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider a vector (or map) of factory functions. The factory functions however would all need the same signature and they would need to return some kind of pointer to a base class.

Ex.

```
// factory functions
// all take no parameters and return a pointer to a shape
unique_ptr<Shape> CreateCircle();
unique_ptr<Shape> CreateSquare();
unique_ptr<Shape> CreateTriangle();

std::vector<std::function<unique_ptr<Shape>()>> factoryVector = 
{
    &CreateCircle,
    &CreateSquare,
    &CreateTriangle
};

// You can now iterate over factoryVector, invoke the () operator on each element
// of the vector, and generate a Shape pointer that points to a Circle, Square, and
// Triangle
```