# How to loop over the public variables of a class in c++?

Tags: c++

How to loop (foreach public variable of class in c++), I have temp_class like the following

```
  class temp_class
    {
    public:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    class2 object_class;

    private:
    //some code here
    }
```

Now I need to get a list of all public variable in the class (some thing similar if we want to get a list of all the properties of a c# class, but for c++ class)

```
temp_class object_class;
//here these is a code to set the values for each public variable in the object

foreach(public_variable in object_class)
{
  string var_name=//get the public variable name
  string var_value=//get the public variable value
}
```

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/314282/489590

Comment: You can't. This is reflexion, not part of c++. What are you trying to do ? there is a better solution for sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/314282/1794345

Comment: SG7 of the LEWG is apparently working on compile-time reflection as a TS along the path of C++1z.  A quick google doesn't see anything more recent than a call for proposals in 2013.  Minutes [here](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3621.pdf) (search for SG7) imply that maybe the working group is not making much progress, but is again from 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. this is C++ , unmanaged code without true reflection.