# Range based for loop for member function of a class?

Tags: c++

I am going to implement a list class and want to iterate through the whole list.

Is this proper C++ to do something like:

```
for (auto i : *this)
```

If not, what would be the proper syntax for a range-based for loop?

Comment: It can be made to work, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: ... it's very strange. Why do you want do this.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, it's basically what I'm asking. Will this syntax work?

Comment: @Stargateur I just need to loop across all the elements in this particular object of the class

Comment: As [documentation suggests](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) range-for is just a syntactic sugar internally evaluated as an ordinary iterator-based loop. So you need to implement an iterator for the set of elements you need to iterate.

Comment: If you need to iterate over members of the object instance, you need to look at various introspection/reflection techniques available for C++. Check [this SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Your list class needs to have suitable `begin()` and `end()` member functions, or else there must be suitable free functions with these names. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for example.

There is nothing special about `this`. If your list class is `L` and `l` has type `L` then you can do:

```
for (auto i : l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
list<T> l{....};
```

Post C++11

```
for(auto & elem : l)
    cout<<elem;
```

Usual Way

```
for(list<T>::iterator it = l.begin();it!=l.end();++it)
    cout<<*it;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the range-for loop is defined as it follows (until C++17):

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    }
}
```

Therefore you have just to define a couple of functions, that are `begin` and `end`. They can be either member functions or accessible via ADL.
This way you'll be able to use your type in a range-for loop, either from within the class itself (using `*this`) or from anywhere else (by using a named variable).

---

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<list>
#include<iostream>

struct my_list {
    using iterator = std::list<int>::iterator;

    friend iterator begin(my_list &);
    friend iterator end(my_list &);

    void f() {
        for(auto v: *this) {
            std::cout << v << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    std::list<int> data{ 0, 1, 2 };
};

my_list::iterator begin(my_list &l) {
    return l.data.begin();
}

my_list::iterator end(my_list &l) {
    return l.data.end();
}

int main() {
    my_list l{};
    l.f();

    for(auto v: l) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```