# Is there a way to view all member elements of a struct in c++?

Tags: c++, struct

I am new to C++. Google didn't help out.
Is there any way to show all member elements of a non user-defined struct? I understand I can always return to the documentation of the struct, but it would be nice if there is a function to which I can pass any struct and get a list of all elements in that struct viewed in the console. 
For example, how can I know the elements in the object myTm which is of type tm (tm is a struct) in the following code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
tm myTm;  //tm is a struct that is included by <ctime>
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Normally you use a software development tool called IDE (Integrated Development Environment) to show you this information

Comment: You would use an IDE for that. Typically Right click->Show definition.

Comment: Works,, thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for reflection (in that case, check out the CppCon 2016 talk on reflections for POD types)...

Comment: You are probably just looking for an IDE feature, but if you want this capability at runtime, then you are out of luck. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows you could use Visual studio IDE , it's nice ,free and it will help you getting all of that.all you have to do is Click `Right` and `go to definition` of that struct .

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is such a function in IDE's.  Right-click the #include and there might be an option to see the declaration. As far as I know, there is no C++ function that solves the problem