# Using an array to store only Names of the data members of a class in C++

Tags: c++, string, data-members

Suppose I have a class as

```
class A {
  char a[15], b[11],c[17];
public:
  void names();

}
void A :: names() {
   char x[20];
   x=a;
   cout<<x;
   x=b;
   cout<<x;
   x=c;
   cout<<x;
}
```

I want to copy data in x from each member of A 
one by one and use a for loop to represent the member names.
is there a way in which I can store them? So something like-

```
    void A :: names() {
           char x[20];
           while(all members of A not traversed){
                 x=current member;
                 cout<<x;
                 update member;
          }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? The question is not clear.

Comment: @Svaberg Thanks for the link

Comment: @Joseph Thomas I will update my question, to clarify. Please do refer.

Comment: @TanishaShrotriya Reflection is not part of the C/C++ language, see e.g. [how can I add reflection to a c application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application). If you just want to store (key, value)-pairs, use a [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). This will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to iterate through a class's members. Like

```
for (variable in a's members) {
    a.x append variable's value
}
```

There is no trivial methods to iterate through a class's members. You should use a [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) instead, which provide iteration features among keys.

```
for (auto const& x : the_map) {
    x.first  // name or key
    x.second // value
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to iterate through a classes members. I will try a map. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to do this in C++ is through pointers.

```
class A {
  char a[15], b[11],c[17];
  char *members[3] = {a, b, c}; // valid only for c++11 or above
public:
  void names();
};

void A::names() {
    for (char *x: members) {  // c++11 range loop...
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

But except if you have strong reasons to use raw char arrays, `std::string` is generally simpler to use...

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with pointers, that's why I went with char arrays. I will try your suggestion though!Thank You.

Comment: @TanishaShrotriya: you cannot assign to an array, that's why I use pointers here. Beware: arrays and pointers are different animals and you should not use one for the other...

Comment: Haha. I tried const char * instead of char *. I think that is where I erred.