# Call method by string and pass arguments

Tags: c++

i search for a way to call a method by its string name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class myClass{
    public:
        void method1(int run){
            std::cout << run << std::endl;
        }
        void method2(int run){
            std::cout << run << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    myClass mc;
    std::string call;

    call = "method1";
    mc.call(1);

    call = "method2";
    mc.call(2);
}
```

But the result, is

> ‘class Myclass’ has no member named ‘call’

I need response "1" and "2";

**EDIT ::** Very thank's for your help, i get the next solution (i don't know is good for all cases );

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class myClass{
public:
    void method1(int run){
        std::cout << "Loaded method => " << run << std::endl;
    }
    void method2(int run){
        std::cout << "Loaded method => " << run << std::endl;
    }
    void _loadMethods(int method, int params){
        switch(method) {
            case 1:
                method1(params);
                break;
            case 2:
                method2(params);
            break;
            default:
                 break;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    myClass mc;
    std::string method;

    method = "method2";

    if(method == "method1"){
         mc._loadMethods(1, 1);
    }
    if(method == "method2"){
        mc._loadMethods(2, 2);
    }
}
```

Thank's

Comment: Try using macros

Comment: C != C++. Tag appropriately.

Comment: I have to get this out of the way: C and C++  are different languages. Now, to answer your question, c++ doesn't support reflection. Consider creating a map with the function's name as key and the function pointer as value

Comment: You cannot do that in C++ without explicitly storing method's name somewhere (maybe with using tricks like macros which may hide that). Information about method names may be lost during compilation and cannot be accessed.

Comment: you dont have any **x** att. in the classs... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Do also note the performance impact of the `std::map` method proposed by @Vanna. Unless, of course, it's determinable at compile time - but what's the point anyway then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add reflection to a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

Comment: @tambre - If one needs to call a function by name whilst using a run-time string, I don't think the slight performance hit is the major problem...

Comment: @Vanna - And the `std::map` lookup, that's not free. A static lookup table may give better performance. Binary search and your'e all set.

Comment: Would you be inclined to share why you want to do this? If this is a "design problem" then a better design is in order. Academic curiosity is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in "raw" C++. But... What you are trying to achieve is some kind of Reflection or Class meta-type information.
You can look at this project: http://www.axelmenzel.de/projects/coding/rttr , use Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details or google for C++ reflection.

Comment: With a modified syntax, it very much is possible. You just have to do the scaffolding yourself.