# Get enum values using reflection google protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Support I have an enum in a `.proto` file such as:

```
enum My_Types
{
  my_types_a = 0;

  my_types_b = 1;

  my_types_c = 2;

}
```

I want to generate an `EnumDescriptor` so that I can can reference values from this enum, but I must use the [Google Reflection APIs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/namespace/google/protobuf/reflection) . When using the protobuf compiled version of the .proto file, I would be able to say `My_Types_descriptor()` to get the `EnumDescriptor`, but how would I do this using reflection? The same would apply for `EnumValueDescriptor` which can describe a particular enum constant.

Given a [DescriptorPool](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#DescriptorPool), how can I use reflection to achieve this? I believe [this API](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/reflection/enum-descriptor) could help, but I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I as looking for was this:

`const EnumDescriptor* enum_desc = Pool->FindEnumTypeByName(custom_type);`

Where `Pool` is a `google::protobuf::DescripterPool` representing the definitions or all the message types and enum described by your protofiles. Once you have the `EnumDescriptor`, then you can use your reflection instance to say `reflection->Getint32()` (or whatever other type you expect) and say

```
const EnumValueDescriptor* enum_value_desc = enum_desc->FindValueByNumber(value);
```

This is give you the value of your enum.

Comment: Side note: you can also get `enum_desc` via `google::protobuf::GetEnumDescriptor<EnumType>()` without having to first get hold of a pool. (There is a `DescripterPool` somewhere, but you don't have to deal with the details yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to be able to do what [EnumDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#EnumDescriptor) does, without generating "Reflection code/data" at compile time to do so? I do not think there is a way to do this. Its a bit confusing what you mean by **must use Reflection**. Really, [EnumDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#EnumDescriptor) is using the C++ version of reflection.

Reflection by default is not available in c++. So if you want it, you have to write your owner parser (like protobuf) or write some magical macro/template code (like this  [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)) to generate the needed data for reflection. You just cant use reflection, you need the metadata about the class's/enums.

Perhaps I could add more if you clarify what you need to do and why?

Comment: When I say reflection, I mean the Google Protocol Buffer Reflection APIs (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/namespace/google/protobuf/reflection) for grabbing messages from a descriptor pool and getting fields. Not looking for a native C++ solution.