# C++ reflection and to/from key value pair (like json)

Tags: c++, reflection, deserialization

I found this answer to kind of do reflection in C++: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748131/5507357

However, I would like to 'expand' this to do 'deserialization'. So for example, I have a json Person object

```
{ 
    "Person": 
    { 
        "name": "Tom",
        "age": 82
    }
}
```

Or an ini file, or xml. How can I create a Person struct with these values with this reflection? The code does not have to 'detect' it is a Person object, it is all about the members.

Comment: do you just wan deserialization or both serialization and deserialization?

Comment: Both is always better but I think if I know how to deserialize, I can find out serialization myself. Hopefully. But if there is a good example for both, that is even better.

I thought about a lambda to do serialization, but I am not 100% sure yet how to implement it (but maybe there are better ways).

Comment: The post you pointed out may do the trick, thus why don't you use this technique?

Comment: I want to use the technique, but I don't understand how you can set the values of the struct from the key as a string. So if you have the key-value pair "name"/"Tom", and the key/value pair "age"/82, how you can set Person.name to "Tom" and Person.age to 82.

Maybe I am thinking too complicated? But I don't see it (yet).

Comment: There are good, stable JSON libraries for C++. Don’t write your own. https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: Thx! But it is not all about json. I know the nlohmann json library indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to look at [Google Protocol Buffers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/&ved=2ahUKEwic2e6oxOviAhWEIVAKHfGKD7AQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2Pd_5ub2crAMBWex3pLFZv&cshid=1560603320905). In C++ reflections are supported and json export. In other languages json import is also supported.

Comment: That's great and much much better than all the macro's. Thanks for pointing me in this direction!