# Built in Functions to see member variable in CPP

Tags: c++, structure

Is there any built in function in CPP to see member variable ?
for example:
'''

```
struct X
{
    data-type var1;
    data-type var2;

};
int main()
{
    struct X A1;
    cout<< func(A1);
    //here the func will return the var1 and var2 for A1 , and print it for me
    return(0);

};
```

'''
**output:**

```
var1var2
```

Comment: You are looking for [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application) which is not readily available in C++

Answer (score 0):

This is no reflection in C++ builtins due to performance penalty. You can check some external libraries like XCppRefl.

Check XCppRefl:
http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/reflcpp/