# C++ static reflection TS: would it support assign/call by name?

Tags: c++, reflection, c++23

There is a [C++ Technical Specification on static reflection](https://github.com/cplusplus/reflection-ts) (current [PDF draft](http://cplusplus.github.io/reflection-ts/draft.pdf) and [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/reflect))
which might move into C++23 or later.

Would it be possible in the current draft (I understand syntax is perhaps not fixed yet)
to access struct fields / call class member functions by name?

For instance

```
struct Test {
  int x;
  int y; 
};

Test foo;

auto meta = reflexpr(foo);  // access meta information about class

some_magic_setter<"x", meta>(foo, 5);  // ??? Should do: `foo.x = 5`
```

Would this be possible and if yes how ?

EDIT: When I look into the TS [draft](http://cplusplus.github.io/reflection-ts/draft.pdf) I find most of the functions are named 'get_XX' (like `get_type`, `get_scope`, ...) or 'is_XXX' (like `is_private`, ...) which seems to to only give information (which is obvoiously the purpose of reflection). However, I cannot find anything that seems to allow member access of a given object. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Are you asking if this is supported in the TS, or if it can be done with the current standard? For the latter, this is a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: @cigien  I am asking only about the TS.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont When I look into the TS I find most of the functions are named 'get_XX' (like `get_type`, `get_scope`, ...) or 'is_XXX' (like `is_private`, ...) which seems to me to give only information (which is obvoiously the purpose of reflection). However, I cannot find anything that seems to allow member access of a given object. Any hints how this is supposed to be done in the TS are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_pointer<X>` gets you a pointer to member, `get_name<X>` gets its name.  Throw in some iterating over members (also supplied), and handling of type mismatching (which could be done in [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03)), and bob is your uncle.

C++ gives compile time reflection primitives; so you have to write the glue code yourself as far as I am aware.

I would start with a function making a tuple of (name member pointer) pairs using reflection.  It can be pure `constexpr`.

Then another function that does setting based on that structure, where runtime failure is in play.

That will let you unit test both pieces seperately; only the building of the "dictionary" requires reflection.

Comment: I guess, that makes sense. So member access is supported indirectly via given pointer (to member). That pretty much answers it.