# C++ designing a static settings structure

Tags: c++, design-patterns, settings, constexpr, variant

I'm trying to write a relatively simple Settings list structure, but after three different failed design iterations, I'm sure I'm missing a keyword to find the name of my exact problem.

#### Ideally, I'd like:

0. Each setting has a unique Key, for easy de(serialisation)
1. Each setting in the list is a class member, or has a named accessor fn, so my IDE can auto-complete
2. Each setting can be a different type (String, uint8_t, uint_16_t...)
3. Each setting has a `const char*` name
4. The list has a compile-time known size and a random-access-iterator, so I can use array subscripting

#### Attempt 1

```cpp
#define MAKE_UNION(struct_name, struct_def)                     \
  struct __dummy_for_size__##struct_name struct_def;            \
                                                                \
  struct struct_name                                            \
  {                                                             \
    union                                                       \
    {                                                           \
      struct struct_def;                                        \
      uint8_t as_list[sizeof(__dummy_for_size__##struct_name)]; \
    };                                                          \
  };

MAKE_UNION(InputSettings, {
  uint8_t source;
  uint8_t channel;
  bool active;
}) input_settings;
```

Pros:

1. When I type `input_settings.s`, IDE can autocomplete to `input_settings.source`
2. Easy array subscripting with `input_settings.as_list[?]`

Cons:

1. Code feels icky, I might be in undefined behaviour land, with the union. I was even casting to `void*` before that...
2. I'm limited to types of one byte, otherwise my `as_list` subscripting falls apart
3. No unique key, (de)serialisation is difficult to make backward/forward compatible
4. Settings don't have a c-str name

#### Attempt 2

Most of the implementation is omitted for brevity

```cpp
struct ISetting{
    const std::string unique_key;
    /*...*/
}; 
class SettingList
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ISetting>> list;
};

class ValueSetting : public ISetting {/*...*/};
class TextValueSetting : public ISetting{/*...*/};



SettingList input_settings;
input_settings.list.push_back(TextValueSetting{"SOURCE", {"A", "B"}, 0});
input_settings.list.push_back(ValueSetting{"CHANNEL", 0, 15, 0});
input_settings.list.push_back(ValueSetting{"ACTIVE", 0, 1, 1});

auto get_source_setting = [&]{
    return input_settings.list[0];
};
```

Pros:

1. Unique keys make it easy to de(serialise)
2. Settings have names

Cons:

1. Too complicated
2. Probably unnecessary runtime polymorphism. Plus because IRL I'm not using RTTI, I have to bake in the type with an enum and add that to the interface in order to downcast.
3. Uses a vector but the size is known
4. Settings don't have named accessors. They have to be written and maintained manually (e.g. the `get_source_setting` lambda).

#### Attempt 3

```cpp
struct Value
{
    uint16_t val;
};
struct TextValue
{
    uint16_t val;
    std::span<std::string_view> values_names;
}; 

std::array<std::pair<std::string, std::variant<Value, TextValue>>, 3> input_settings
{{
    {"SOURCE",  TextValue{ /*... */ }},
    {"CHANNEL", Value{ /*... */ }},
    {"ACTIVE",  Value{ /*... */ }},
    //...
    //...
}};
```

Pro:

1. Unique key
2. Random access
3. Could abstract away into a class for easy `get_by_key(std::string)`

Cons:

1. No named accessor
2. Non random access iterator
3. Wasted memory because of the memory layout of std::variant (minor inconvenience)

Even a `get_by_key(std::string)` would imply a runtime performance cost. Maybe a compile time `get<key_t>()` is possible ?

## TL;DR:

How can I mix and match different types into a container, and have each element have its own dedicated named getter/setter automatically ? All the elements are known at compile time, I'd like to avoid runtime overhead.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please note that all symbols starting with double underscore are reserved, and should not be declared or defined by your code. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: You might be in danger of trying to micro-optimise here.  Also, why do you need `operator[]`?  I've never needed that in my settings class.

Comment: I think perhaps you are asking how to do *reflection* in C++, in which case the question [How can I add reflection to a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application) might help.

Comment: @PaulSanders I think you're right, the `operator[]` is a previous bad decision which I didn't take time to reconsider.

@ScottMcPeak Thanks for mentioning reflection, I found boost::pfr which seems to provide a good workflow for my use case.