# Array of void functions in c++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In a c++ desktop application I have a number of void functions like:

```
void myfunction01(wxCommandEvent& event);
void myfunction02(wxCommandEvent& event);
...
```

Then I have an array of wxButtons named BUTTON.

I would like to bind the functions to the buttons in a loop like:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
BUTTON[i]->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::function[i], this);
}
```

But I cannot find a way to put those functions in an array...
Is there a way to do it?
I saw other similar questions but none of them helped me out

Comment: Could you add a little bit of code to make a [mcve].  It worked for me, but that might be because the code I added to fill in the gaps was not sufficiently like your code.

Comment: There should be a way, just store those functions in a vector or map and access it by index or name.

Comment: are they free functions or class member functions ?

Comment: They are class member functions

Comment: You have 100 member functions?

Comment: It is just an example to explain the issue

Comment: @rEbbasta, why? What would be the purpose of such code? Just bind the function to the button as you see fit, unless you have a scrolled window with millions of buttons. But then your program will not work, at least on Windows,  where you have a limit of 10k handles per process...

Comment: It sounds like what your looking for is a reflection api so that you can iterate over your object's methods and form an array and then iterate over that array to bind them to button events. Unfortunately c++ currently doesn't have a reflection api, but there are [a few options available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application) to partially implement one yourself.

Comment: Re: "void functions" -- the return type of the function doesn't affect how you store function pointers in an appropriately typed array.

Answer (score 2):

You might create an array like that:

```
const std::array<void (MyFrame::*)(wxCommandEvent&), 100> functions = {{
    &MyFrame::myfunction01,
    &MyFrame::myfunction02,
// ...
}};
```

with then

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    BUTTON[1 + i]->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, function[i], this);
}
```

But, avoiding the loop might make more sense here.
function seems unrelated.
(else `void myfunction01(int index, wxCommandEvent& event);` might make sense).

So I would even add the binding to the specific button, and not from the array.

```
// BUTTON[1] = /*..*/
BUTTON[1]->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::myfunction01, this);
// BUTTON[2] = /*..*/
BUTTON[2]->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::myfunction02, this);
// BUTTON[3] = /*..*/
BUTTON[3]->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::myfunction03, this);
// ...
```